# minimum working distance to track moving object with kinect

Tags: kinect

I'm wondering what the minimum working distance for the Kinect is.

I'd like to track a moving object (`10cm x 10cm`) from a distance of `1m`. The area that the object will be moving in, is `120cm x 60cm`.

Given Kinect's specs, will it be possible to track the object across the entire area?

Comment: Have you tried it? I don't see why not, the living room you are expected to play in is actually larger. You might have issues with tracking rate and whether your movement in this area is fast or slow (slower will be better as the frame rate will be less of a problem).

Comment: I didn't buy it yet and would like to know whether it will work before I get one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect#Technology):

> The sensor has an angular field of view of 57° horizontally and 43°
>   vertically

so the answer to your question would be: no, 120cm would be too wide. Since the maximum horizontal viewing field at 1m would be [tan(57deg/2)*2](https://www.google.com/search?q=tan%2857deg/2%29%2a2) = ~1.08m

though at a distance of ~1.2m it should work ([tan(57deg/2)*2*1.2](https://www.google.com/search?q=tan%2857deg/2%29%2a2%2a1.2) = ~1.3m)

Answer (score 1):

Distance range handled by the sensor is **850mm minimum** and **4000mm maximum**, so this should be possible.

I strongly recommend watching the [Kinect SDK Quickstarts videos](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectSDKQuickstarts) as it covers all basics to get you started. In fact the ["Working with depth data"](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectSDKQuickstarts/Working-with-Depth-Data) probably contains exactly the kind of info you're looking for.